# Values of dictionary are not changing

Tags: swift, core-graphics

```
var frameSizeInfo = [String:CGSize]()
frameSizeInfo["productSize"] = logs.productSize as CGSize
frameSizeInfo["pictureWithMatSize"] = logs.pictureWithMatSize
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("FrameSizeThings", object: frameSizeInfo)
```

I got error an like:

> Cannot convert value of type `[string:CGSize]` to expected argument
>   type `AnyObject?`

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var frameSizeInfo = [String: NSValue]()
frameSizeInfo["productSize"] = NSValue(CGSize: logs.productSize as CGSize)
frameSizeInfo["pictureWithMatSize"] = NSValue(CGSize: logs.pictureWithMatSize)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("FrameSizeThings", object: nil, userInfo: frameSizeInfo)
```

You use `object` parameter as object posting the notification, `userInfo` parameter - as `[NSObject : AnyObject]?` dictionary of custom parameters

Since `CGSize` is struct, you can not cast it to `AnyObject` type. Use `NSValue` class with `CGSize:` initializer to wrap `CGSize`. You can use `CGSizeValue()` method for `NSValue` instances for unwrap `CGSize` later.

Comment: Again i am getting cannot convert value of type [string:CGSize] to expected argument Type [NSObject : AnyObject]?

Comment: could you help in this ?